# Переход из Navbar в Section

Tags: html, css

Имеется сайт на html css, как сделать преход из navbar в section.
В Navbar имеется кнопка "Сотрудничать", при нажатии должно переходить на section "Регистрация". Как это реализуется, подскажи пожалуйста.

Comment: [http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya)